# Datatable Ajax.Reload

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a Datatable that loads when the page is first loaded.
Here is the ajax call.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#queueListSelect").dataTable({
        "ajax": {
        "url": "-,
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "success": function(data){
            var numberOfMessages = 0;
            for(var key in data.queueInformation){
                numberOfMessages++;
                $("#queueListSelect tbody").append('<tr id= "row'+numberOfMessages+'"><td id="queueName'+numberOfMessages+'">'+data.queueInformation[key].queueName+'</td><td>'+data.queueInformation[key].pendingMessageCount+'</td><td>'+data.queueInformation[key].pendingMessageSize+'</td><td>'+data.queueInformation[key].receiverCount+'</td><td>'+data.queueInformation[key].inTotalMessages+'</td><td>'+data.queueInformation[key].outTotalMessages+'</td><td>'+data.queueInformation[key].receiverCount+'</td></tr>');
            }
            //success function requires a return, this removes the "loading" row that appears in the dataTable
            $("#queueListSelect td.dataTables_empty").remove();
          }
        },
        "paging":   false,
        "scrollY": "390px",
        "scrollX":  true,
        "info":     false
    });
});
```

After submitting a message, I would like the dataTable to reload using the ajax.reload feature, so as you will see I have another ajax call for submitting the message information.

```
        var queueTable = $("queueListSelect").DataTable();

    if ($("input[name=messageType]:checked").val() == "text"){
        var textBody = $('#textMessageBody').val();

        $.ajax ({
            url: "",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({"queueName": queueName, "textBody": textBody, "jmsDeliveryMode": jmsDeliveryMode, "jmsDestination": jmsDestination, "jmsCorrelationID": jmsCorrelationID, "jmsType": jmsType, "jmsExpiration": jmsExpiration, "jmsPriority": jmsPriority}),
            success: function() {
                alert("Your message was sent"); 
            },
            complete: function(){
                $("#messageModalCloseButton").click();
                queueTable.clear();
                **queueTable.ajax.reload();**
            }
        });
```

Once this message is sent the modal will close and the table SHOULD be updated from the information sent in the message. There are currently no errors in my debugger and when I put a breakpoint on it, it shows that it runs- which is odd because the table does not contain the new information. Once I refresh the page, the new information appears.

Any ideas why this datatables feature is not working?
I am using jquery and datatables version 1.10.

Comment: You're missing a '#' in `var queueTable = $("queueListSelect").DataTable();`

Comment: @markpsmith, please add this as an answer.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com - really? a) it's over a year old. b) the problem was due to a typo so is unlikely to help anyone else.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @markpsmith, still, it helps not to stumble on this question over and over when going over unanswered question.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com - In that case should it not be deleted? I don't feel it's of use to anybody, and in fact it's misleading.  The OP hasn't been on since aug2014 so probably won't be bothered, and is unlikely to mark it as answered so it will STILL appear in the unanswered list. What do you think?

Comment: @markpsmith, maybe you're right, it has no value. I assume that the question title is what brought 2K views.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I've flagged it for deletion, thanks for highlighting it.